# Unable to view Logs under Cloudwatch for AWS MQ

Tags: terraform, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, amazon-mq

Below TF code executes without issues and also creates MQ broker but I am unable to see the logs of MQ under CloudWatch log stream group which is by default created. Could any one suggest me where I am missing so that I can add cloudwatch enable under main.tf?

```
resource "aws_mq_broker" "broker" {
  broker_name = "example-mq"

  tags = merge(
    var.common_tags,
    map("Classification", "private"),
    map("Name", "example-mq")
  )

  configuration {
    id       = "${aws_mq_configuration.mq-config.id}"
    revision = "${aws_mq_configuration.mq-config.latest_revision}"
  }

  apply_immediately = true

  engine_type                = "ActiveMQ"
  engine_version             = "5.15.9"
  auto_minor_version_upgrade = true
  deployment_mode            = "ACTIVE_STANDBY_MULTI_AZ"
  subnet_ids                 = "subnet-12341234123"
  security_groups            = "sg-123123123"
  host_instance_type         = "mq.m5.large"
  publicly_accessible        = false

  user {
    username       = "mq_username"
    password       = "mq_password"
    groups         = "admin_group"
    console_access = true
  }

  logs {
    general = true
    audit   = false
  }

  depends_on = ["aws_mq_configuration.mq-config"]
}


resource "aws_mq_configuration" "mq-config" {
  name           = "mq-config"
  engine_type    = "ActiveMQ"
  engine_version = "5.15.9"
  data           = "${data.template_file.mq_configuration_data.rendered}"

  tags = merge(
    var.common_tags,
    map("Classification", "private"),
    map("Name", "mq-config")
  )

  depends_on = ["data.template_file.mq_configuration_data"]
}

# data for MQ broker configuration
data "template_file" "mq_configuration_data" {
  template = "${file("files/data.xml.tpl")}"

  vars = {
    upload                   = upload
    processing               = processing
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Amazon MQ documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazon-mq/latest/developer-guide/security-logging-monitoring-configure-cloudwatch.html#security-logging-monitoring-configure-cloudwatch-resource-permissions), you need to create a resource-based policy to allow Amazon MQ to publish logs to CloudWatch:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "mq_logs" {
  statement {
    actions = [
      "logs:CreateLogStream",
      "logs:PutLogEvents",
    ]

    resources = ["arn:aws:logs:*:*:log-group:/aws/amazonmq/*"]

    principals {
      identifiers = ["mq.amazonaws.com"]
      type        = "Service"
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_resource_policy" "mq_logs" {
  policy_document = data.aws_iam_policy_document.mq_logs.json
  policy_name     = "mq-logs"
}
```